# PHP While Loop Counter

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

I have a While loop counter that counts all the rows in the SQL query. I want to display the all the rows but want to insert a Totals row after a row has occurred x amount of times. X varies depending on the amount of times that x occurs in rows. How can I do this?

The counter needs to reset after every condition has been met.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of code I use:

```
$PgN = $a_rows->Page;
$counter;
While($sumPageGet = sqlsrv_fetch_object(execPageGet){
$sumPageTot = $sumPageGet->NoOfPages;
$sumPage = $sumPageGet->Page;
If($counter == $sumPageTot){
//do something
}
Else
{
$counter++;
}
```

It is important to realise that I am doing 2 seperate queries.  One query to get all rows in table and another to sum all the rows. I need to know how many times a Page number occurs in the Page column and then only increment the counter when the row value occurs in both queries. So every time X == X ot needs to increment.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Both unclear and too broad on this question. You ned to show what you've tried.

Comment: @Tandpyn Your question isn't clear. For example the statement `So every time X == X ot needs to increment` - isn't it always the case that `X == X`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work.

```
$counter = 0;
$array = aray(1,2,3...);

While($array) {
your code 
counter (e.g. $counter = +1;)
if($counter = 10) {
echo "Something";
}
```

When your counter reaches certain number the condition in the loop is met and then condition does something.

Comment: Just a note, we should not be rewarding zero-effort on the OP's part, especially when there is no sample code to go from. I realize you are trying to score some points, but we should not be encouraging proper questions from being asked.